# ScrollViewer scrollbars not appearing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm working on updating previously working app.  Testing shows the ScrollViewer acting oddly when the Zoom makes part of the contained images fall off the screen.  The original app was created with VS 2013 as a Universal Windows app.  The new app is created with VS 2015 as a Universal Windows app though the target build has been shifted to the anniversary release.

My XAML is defined so:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="SV1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        SizeChanged="SV1_SizeChanged" ZoomMode="Enabled" >               
    <StackPanel x:Name="ImagePanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <Image x:Name="ImageLeft" Stretch="Uniform" />
        <Image x:Name="ImageRight" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The user can change the ZoomLevel of the ScrollViewer.  The zoom change is implemented using SV1.ChangeView(null, null, zoomFactor).

The images visibly change size on the screen, but as they fall off the right or bottom the scrollbars don't appear.  Even changing the visibility properties to "Visible" instead of "Auto" doesn't cause the scrollbars to appear.  When the size changes and for a brief instant a thin line will appear where the bars should be and then disappear.  Additionally, user input that would normally scroll like moving the mouse wheel does nothing.

Based on other commentary, I've tried replacing the StackPanel with a Grid with no apparent effect.

I'm drawing a blank.  Any ideas?

Comment: The usual reason for this is that the ScrollViewer is expanding to accomodate its content. Try setting VerticalAlignment="Stretch" on the Grid that contains it -- but this is going to depend on the whole context, out to the Window. This stuff is a very painful part of XAML, for me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the answer is the next control which shares the same visual space needs to be set to `Visibility="Collapsed"` in the XAML.  The visibility is controlled programmatically, but without the XAML tag the scrollbars of the previous control don't appear and with the tag they do.